# VB.NET TCP Socket Programming - Send an Array of String

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

i want to make program that implement socket programming both TCP and UDP.
Here is the flow : 
1. I have an array of string with 10 string. 
2. Im using TCP Client Program that send the array of string to TCP Server 
3. And i try to send the whole string that i receive with TCP server program to UDP.

But the problem is when im trying to send a string from TCP client to string.
its not what i expected.

The String i want to Send to TCP Server :

```
Dim strMessage(10) As String
        strMessage(0) = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        strMessage(1) = "Etiam imperdiet erat vitae elit faucibus, et accumsan est facilisis."
        strMessage(2) = "Duis elementum ante et quam sagittis molestie at ac nulla."
        strMessage(3) = "Pellentesque a metus eget metus aliquam pharetra in sed nibh."
        strMessage(4) = "Ut ut eros sit amet nisi consequat vulputate."
        strMessage(5) = "Fusce vel dui at purus laoreet consequat."
        strMessage(6) = "Donec sed erat lacinia, aliquam ante eu, pulvinar ligula."
        strMessage(7) = "Vestibulum posuere elit facilisis orci sagittis, id feugiat mi aliquam."
        strMessage(8) = "Donec sit amet lectus ut nibh pharetra dapibus ut vitae nulla."
        strMessage(9) = "Maecenas quis nunc scelerisque, cursus nibh tristique, pulvinar ipsum."
```

TCP client code :

```
Dim stm As Stream
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Do
            stm = tcpClient.GetStream() 'getting the stream of the client
            Dim ascenc As New ASCIIEncoding
            Dim byteData() As Byte = ascenc.GetBytes(strMessage(counter))
            Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitted ")
            stm.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length())

            counter += 1

        Loop While counter < 10
```

TCP Server Code :

```
Dim bitData(100) As Byte
    Do
        Try
            Dim size As Integer = TcpSocket.Receive(bitData)
            Console.WriteLine(size.ToString)
            Dim newString As String
            'Dim chars(size) As Char

            'chars(i) = Convert.ToChar(bitData(i))
            newString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bitData)

            'Dim newString As New String(chars)
            Console.WriteLine(newString)
            strMessage(counter) = newString


            counter += 1

            If counter = 9 Then
                state = 2
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Write(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    Loop While state = 1
    TcpListener.Stop()
    TcpSocket.Close()
```

The string what i got from the program : 
This is the message you received: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
This is the message you received: Etiam imperdiet erat vitae elit faucibus, et accumsan est facilisis.
This is the message you received: Duis elementum ante et quam sagittis molestie at ac nulla.facilisis.
This is the message you received: Pellentesque a metus eget metus aliquam pharetra in sed nibh.ilisis.
This is the message you received: Ut ut eros sit amet nisi consequat vulputate.tra in sed nibh.ilisis.
This is the message you received: Fusce vel dui at purus laoreet consequat.ate.tra in sed nibh.ilisis.
This is the message you received: Donec sed erat lacinia, aliquam ante eu, pulvinar ligula.ibh.ilisis.
This is the message you received: Vestibulum posuere elit facilisis orci sagittis, id feugiat mi aliquam.
This is the message you received: Donec sit amet lectus ut nibh pharetra dapibus ut vitae nulla. aliquam.

The string that tcp server got, its just : 9 String and isnt the string what i want.

Thank for your help
im so sorry with my bad grammar.

Comment: You can add an End-of-Message character to each message so that you'll know that you have read the entire message at your server side

Comment: Shouldn't If counter = 9 Then be If counter = 10 Then as you are incrementing counter after processing the message?